# Profile has no user

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to use context processor to show profile page and when I use it the website shows

> Profile has no user

Context processor:

```py
from .models import  Profile

    def get_profile (request):
        profile =  Profile()
        return{'information':profile}
```

models.py

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("user"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_("image"), upload_to='profile_img', blank=True, null=True)
    country = CountryField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(_("join date"),default = datetime.datetime.now)
```

Also I made primary url for profile so when I want to go to profile page I write on url

> accounts/profile/mohammad

account is the name of apps,
profile is the  name of page,
mohammad is user name

Hints: I want to use profile.html on dropdown menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Profile` for the given user with:

```
def get_profile (request):
    profile = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    return {'information': profile }
```

or as [@xyres says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70326289/profile-has-no-user/70326327?noredirect=1#comment124316607_70326327):

```
def get_profile (request):
    profile = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile = getattr(user, 'profile', None)
    return {'information': profile }
```

For a user that is not authenticated, or has no `Profile`, `information` will be `None`, otherwise it is a `Profile` object with as `.user` the logged in user.

If you want to access of the user specified by a slug for example, you use the view, so you can define a path:

```
path('accounts/profile/<slug:username>/', some_view)
```

and then we can use:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def some_view(request, username):
    profile = get_objec_or_404(Profile, slug=username)
    # …
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'information': profile})
```

Comment: Isn't `filter().first()` unnecessary? Can't you just access the profile using `user.profile` since it is a OneToOne relation?

Comment: @xyres: yes, but this will raise an `AttributeError` in case this is a user without a `Profile`, to prevent this from happening, one can query the other way around.

Comment: @xyres: returning `None` in case there is no `Profile` is a feature that has been asked multiple times, but for backwards compatibility, this misfeature will probably still remain.

Comment: `getattr(user, 'profile', None)`?

Comment: @xyres: that's also a possibility yes :)